# How to get the key of a child based of the object in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the _random number in firebase using node.js and encapsulate it in my notifications body section.? I tried to create an array and read everything from firebase into the array but it didn't help

```js
exports.sendFigureNotification = functions.database.ref('_random').onWrite(event => {
var rootRef = admin.database().ref();
rootRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {

    
});

 const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Title',
            body: 'The Cloud Function works',  //use _random to get figure at index key
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default'
        }
    };
    
    const options = {
       priority:"high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24, //24 hours
        content_available: true
    };
   const topic = "HBF"
   console.log('Sending notifications');
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options);
 
});
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t22Ou.png

Comment: *"My current code is: `blabla` but it does not works for some reason. I have also searched Google and found this, this and this, but I'm unable to figure out how to solve this problem."* would help and show that you really tried to solve your own problem.

Comment: Roko I updated my description